# How to convert unsigned char* to an unsigned char array in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, interop

My function looks something like this:

```
void Example(const unsigned char* bytes)
{
    unsigned char buffer[2048] = {0};
    strcpy(buffer, bytes);
}
```

This does not work. How do I make this work?

Comment: Given the name `bytes`, you should have a length parameter. 0 is a valid byte.

Comment: _"This does not work."_ How does this not work? Do you get a compiler error?

Comment: A cast never changes anything, it just makes the compiler look at something with different glasses. It may change how something is *viewed*, but it doesn't change *the thing*.

Comment: @ThomasSablik it says "argument of type "unsigned char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"

Comment: @chris I am not really sure how exactly to do this because this function will basically be called externally by C# and pass a byte array as an argument. I wasn't sure how to convert it into C++ but I read that it had to be an unsigned char array. Also, I just put the length as 2048 because that will always be enough, but I feel like I'm making some kind of mistake here. I don't code in C++, usually.

Comment: @ThomasSablik presumably it cuts corners and takes a lot of sick leave

Comment: @GrünerBaum, I'm talking about the function signature. C# is well capable of passing in the length of the array it passes as a second argument. Then your function would work with data that contains `0` bytes because it wouldn't assume that's the end of the data. If this _is_ a C string, `bytes` is a rather misleading name.

Comment: @GrünerBaum that error possibly sounds like you tried to call the function using a "char *", as opposed to an "unsigned char *"? Have you checked if that's the case?

Comment: maybe you meant unsigned char buffer[2048] = "" ? its a valid c-like initialization-by-zeroes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you  do need to convert anything. if you want to copy from one

```
void Example(const void *bytes, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char buffer[2048];
    memcpy(buffer, bytes, len);
    /* ...*/ 
}
```

example usage

```
int foo(void)
{
    char str[] = "Hello world";
    Example(str, sizeof(str));
}
```

Comment: Did you mean char str* = "Hello world"; ? Because this just converts an array to an array.

Comment: While pointers and arrays are not the same thing arrays decay into pointers in function calls so technically this is the same thing as * except for the pointer string literal and array string literal part.

Comment: @GrünerBaum `char str* = "Hello world";` it is not valid C code. So for sure I did not mean it. `char *str = "Hello world";` yes - it does not matter in this case

Answer (score 0):

As others may have mentioned, `strcpy` works on arrays of type `char`, not `unsigned char`, and the source array must be zero-terminated.

If you are not limited to C, but can also use c++, you may use `std::vector` as your buffer. I assume that `bytes` does not point to a zero terminated array, and that you therefore need an additional length parameter:

```
void Example(const unsigned char* bytes, size_t n)
{
   // Pointers can in c++ be used as iterators
   // 
   std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(bytes, bytes+n);
}
```

This lets you in a safe way, not be bound to a maximum buffer size.

The data in a `std::vector` is stored sequentially in memory, so if you need a pointer to the data, just do `const unsigned char *b = &buffer[0];`